# Customize Yocto build by condition

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I have image and I need installer version of this image.
In installer version differs from cunsumers version by one line in `/etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini` and other passwords of root and user.
What is better way of generation two images with minor differences?

I have created in my layer
`layer/recipes-core/images`
another file
`image-installer.bb`
similar to
`image-consumer.bb`

And want to choose version by typing `bitbake image-installer(consumer)`

and in `image-installer.bb` I have add lines for changing passwords:

```
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P user password;"
```

But how should I change `/etc/xdg/wayland/weston.ini`?
I add to `image-installer.bb` lines

```
do_install_append() {
  install -D -p ${WORKDIR}/weston_for_installer.ini ${D}${sysconfdir}/xdg/weston/weston.ini
  #or
  sed -i "/\[shell\]/apanel-position=none" ${D}${sysconfdir}/xdg/weston/weston.ini
}
```

but this lines does not changes anything

Answer (score 2):

First of all and regarding the handling of the 2 images themselve, I would create a common class from which inherit both of your image recipes, something like that :

1. **custom-image-base.bbclass**

   ```
   SUMMARY = "..."
   IMAGE_INSTALL = "..."

   inherit core-image

   <other common stuff>
   ```
2. **image-consumer.bb**

   ```
   inherit custom-image-base
   ```
3. **image-installer.bb**

   ```
   inherit custom-image-base

   <do special action here or install additional recipe which modify the final image>
   ```

From here, there is perhaps multiple solutions but the most simple is to modify the rootfs after its complete creation. You can do it in image recipes using the ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND helper. You can also manage user creation/modification from this recipe:

**image-installer.bb**

```
inherit custom-image-base extrausers

modify_wayland_ini_file() {
    if [ -f "${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/xdg/weston/weston.ini" ]; then
        sed -i "/\[shell\]/apanel-position=none" ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/xdg/weston/weston.ini
    fi
}
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "modify_wayland_ini_file;"

# printf "%q" $(mkpasswd -m sha256crypt myawesomepwd)
PWD = "\$5\$NWH15.mb3GHy61Je\$2YAfr4Nj1uGFfEokXzSQpLGreZ06b3LbEwZOya762gB"

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " useradd -u 1000 admin; \
                       usermod -p '${PWD}' admin; \
                       usermod -a -G sudo admin;"
```